# Debugging a mysql 1044 error

Tags: mysql-error-1044

What is the best way to figure out the cause of a mysql 1044 error?

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'web'@'%' to database some_db
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`show grants for web@%` would be the best way. If you don't get back anything, or what HAS been granted doesn't cover what's being requested, there's your problem...